# Apache Wicket: dynamic key for message with embedded HTML

Tags: java, internationalization, wicket

Wicket supports complex translatable message containing HTML elements like links, etc. as described in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization using wicket:message. E.g.:

```
<wicket:message key="messageKey">
    <a wicket:id="link"><wicket:message key="linkLabel"></wicket:message></a>
</wicket:message>
```

and the properties:

```
messageKey=Click on ${link}
```

and in Java

```
add(new BookmarkablePage<Void>("link", SomePage.class);
```

This works great, however the message key is hardcoded in the HTML.

In my case, I want the message key to be dynamically determined in Java. For regular messages (with string parameters) I can do that with a `Label` and a `StringResourceModel` that takes the key as a parameter. But how do I do the same thing for a message that contains Wicket components as parameters? I guess the markup would looks something like:

```
<span wicket:id="messageId">
    <a wicket:id="link"><wicket:message key="linkLabel"></wicket:message></a>
<span>
```

But what would the Java be? `Label` cannot have children. :(

=== UPDATE ===

There's a Wicket class `org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.WicketMessageResolver.MessageContainer` that looks interesting. Since it's private static, I cannot use it directly but if I copy paste the code into a public class and tweak a couple things related to component hierarchy, I'm getting close to a solution. But that's pretty hacky. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up copying / modifying Wicket's private class MessageContainer (nested in org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.WicketMessageResolver) like so:

https://gist.github.com/totof3110/cf5f05731816a58d8597

Then I can have Java code like:

```
final String messageKey;
if (userLoggedIn) {
    messageKey = "logged.in";
} else {
    messageKey = "logged.out";
}
MessageContainer message = new MessageContainer("message", messageKey);
BookmarkablePageLink<Void> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("link", UserProfilePage.class);
link.add(new Label("username", user.getUsername());
message.add(link);
add(message);
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<span wicket:id="message">
    <a wicket:id="link"><span wicket:id="username"></span></a>
</span>
```

The properties files looks like:

```
logged.in = ${link} logged in.
logged.out = ${link} logged out.
```

Depending on whether userLoggedIn is true or false the rendered HTML will look like:

```
<a href="/profile">totof3110</a> logged in.
```

or

```
<a href="/profile">totof3110</a> logged out.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<wicket:message key="messageKey">
   <a wicket:id="link">...</a>
</wicket:message>
```

doesn't look correct. It should rather be:

```
<a wicket:id="link"><wicket:message key="messageKey"/></a>
```

because I guess you want the label to be clickable. A label is a text (i.e. HTML text node), so it cannot have children HTML elements.

Same is valid for the Java side - the Link should be the parent of the Label.

HTH

Comment: Sorry my example might be confusing. What I'm trying to do is have a translatable resource with parameters that are Wicket components (bookmarkable links, ajax links, etc.) AND have a dynamic message key. The wicket:message tag works great as I can nest all sorts of Wicket component in there, but the message key has to be entered in the HTML, so I cannot dynamically choose it.

Comment: You can construct your own component that uses Localizer class to get the i18n values. To get the localizer: application.getResourceSettings().getLocalizer(). Then user its getString() methods as you find appropriate. It is hard for me to understand your problem. Please provide a sample output and mark which part of it is i18n and which is another component.

Comment: I've added an answer with what I'm currently using. Let me know if you can think of a better solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setBody()` method for any link to use any model as link-text.

For example:

```
Link l = new AjaxLink("linkid");
l.setBody(new StringResourceModel(...));
```

With HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="linkid">this text will be replaced by the model</a>
```